# Storing tri-grams in database or generate on-the-fly?

Tags: string-matching, n-gram

I'm trying to create an application which uses trigrams for approximate string matching. Now all the records are in the database and i want to be able to search the records on a fixed column. Is it best to have an additional field whihc contains the hashed version of the value i want to search (if so, whats the best way to store it?) or is it better to generate the trigrams on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which database are you using?

PostgreSQL has trigram functions built in which work off of GiST or GiN indexes.

In SQL, I'm using CLR to create and compare trigram sets, works much, much faster than SQL code.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL 2008 R2

Comment: OK, us too. We're generating the trigrams on insert into a column (or more if necessary) on the same table. I use an AFTER INSERT trigger which calls a CLR function which generates a sorted string of the trigrams for each row. When comparing, we also use a CLR function to analyse the percentage match between two pre-generated concatenated trigram strings. We found that using CLR to do both the generation and comparisons were many times faster than looping or set based SQL code.

Comment: I've built a CLR function now that compares a given string to each of the records inside the database. This function can be called in the where statement like TrigramMatch('string', fieldname) > 0.8 (match factor). Is there any difference in doing the generation every time and storing them in the database? I only got one field available in database. I currently can search 20.000 records in about 0.3 second.

Comment: I think it just depends on how many times you're going to do the comparison; if only once then there's no real reason to store anything; but if you're going to do the comparisons many times then it makes sense to only generate the trigram string once per entry rather than once per row per comparison.

Comment: Well, they are going to be requested a lot more times... However, if i need to store them in one field there is a lot of overhead too for splitting the generated trigrams + counts again...

Comment: This is where it's important to 1) organise the generated & concatenated trigram set string so that it's ordered alphabetically and contains no duplicates (which helps step 2); and 2) optimise the comparison CLR code such that it minimises the work, by "stepping through" each string by 3-letter-steps and increasing a match count with each match. This minimises the number of operations required to compare the strings.